# Cookie creation in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework, cookies, zend-framework2

I need one help in creating cookie in zend framework 2.

I couldn't figure it out the correct way to implement it. I have tried to create cookie object and assign using code from [Zend Http Client documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.http.client.advanced.html#adding-cookies-and-using-cookie-persistence).

This does not gives me error , so i assumed it that cookies has been created , but i couldn't assign time of expiration in it , and how to get this two cookie variable data which i have created and check whether this cookie exists.

I need help on these , If I have coded wrong then please show me the code to how to create a cookie and later check it whether it exists and then fetch the value from it?

Comment: Can you add the exact code you have used into question instead of the link to manual?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @foozy Ihave used this code     $cookies = new \Zend\Http\Client();
                              $cookies->addCookie('emailcookie', $email);
                              $cookies->addCookie('passwordcookie', $password);  but i couldn't assign time of expiration in it , and how to get this two cookie variable data which i have created and check whether this cookie exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This my code to create , this might help others for zend framework 2 =>

```php
$cookie1 = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie('emailcookie', $email, time() + (((30*24)*60)*60));
$cookie2 = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie('passwordcookie', $password, time() + (((30*24)*60)*60));

$this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie1);
$this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie2);

// For unsetting cookie:
$getcookie=$request->getCookie(); // returns object of Zend\Http\Header\Cookie

$chkemailcookieexist=$getcookie->offsetExists('emailcookie');

$chkpasswordcookieexist=$getcookie->offsetExists('passwordcookie');

// var_dump($chkemailcookieexist);
$prevdatetime=strtotime('-1 day', strtotime(date('Y-m-d')));

if($chkemailcookieexist)
{
    $cookie1 = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie('emailcookie', $email,$prevdatetime);
    $this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie1);
}

// var_dump($chkpasswordcookieexist);
if($chkpasswordcookieexist)
{
    $cookie2 = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie('passwordcookie', $password, $prevdatetime);
    $this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie2);
}
```

Comment: Storing password in cookie is really bad idea. Cookies are vulnerable. Even if password is hashed, it's not safe.

Comment: yeah thats is true then how are you going to implement rememeber me @lku

Comment: I think, it would be better to create an another question, if you have any specific problem with that. But there is a lot of resources about this topic, for example this article: http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetCookie header class ([Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.3/classes/Zend.Http.Header.SetCookie.html)). For example in your controller:

```
$cookie = new SetCookie('cookieName', 'cookieValue', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1);
$this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);
```

Check the class constructor, you can set there all needed flags.

Then you can read cookies from *Zend\Http\Request*, for example in controller:

```
$cookieValue = $this->getRequest()->getCookie()->cookieName;
```

Where getCookie method returns *Zend\Http\Header\Cookie* which is ArrayObject and contains all cookies from request.

Comment: Hi @lku If this way cookie gets created then what is the code  to fetch data from cookie and check whether it exists or not , in zend framework 2

Comment: Hi @lku thanks i have done it , i have got idea from your code it was helpful ,could you tell me code to  unset a cookie variable in zend framework 2

Comment: @Soumik : You need to send same cookie with expiration date in the past. Browser will delete that cookie in next request.

Comment: Hi @lku can we use any unset method of cookie class to do that , actually i was going through some methods of cookie class , but didn't worked .